# Debian repository & apt problems

Tags: debian, apt, software-installation, repository

I'm on fresh Debian 10 install.

When I try to install **`openvpn`** with `apt`, it shows *package not found*.

Running `apt update` changes nothing.

As I think `openvpn` must surely be in repo I realise that there must be some problems in my `sources.list`.

My sources file contains this:

```
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main repository is missing in your `sources.list`. To add it with the `contrib` repository, add these two lines (binary and source packages) to your `sources.list`:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib
```

Then run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openvpn
```

See: [Example sources.list](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Example_sources.list) (Debian wiki)